# the programme codes of language c about input and output are wrong,could somebody help me find the fault?

Tags: c

I have the following code in c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a, b, c, sum;
    double d, p;
    sum = a + b + c;
    printf("请输入三个整数：");
    scanf("%d %d %d", &a, &b, &c);
    d = sum / 3;
    printf("3个整数的平均值是：d=%.2f", d);
    p = a / sum * 100;
    printf("，第一个数占和的比例是：p=%4.2f%%", p);
}
```

It is about entering three integers from the keyboard, average them, and calculate the ratio of the first number to the sum of the three numbers. The output result retains 2 decimal places .
I cannot find where is wrong.

Comment: You want to translate your prompts to English (or eliminate them).  What is your input, output and expected output?

Comment: You're literally telling it to print two decimal places with `.2f`

Comment: First need to input the numbers `a,b,c` and then calculate the `sum`. If you first calculate the sum and then make the input, the program will provide garbage values to `a,b,c` and `sum`. And another problem is the data type. Here `a,b,c, sum` variables are integer but `d,p` are double. So you have to change the datatype of `a,b,c, sum` or type cast the `sum` while calculating d and p.

Answer (score 3):

The two main issues are:

1. You calculate `sum` with uninitialized values for `a`, `b` and `c`.  Move that calculation to after a successful `scanf()` to ensure those variables are set.
2. You probably want to do the calculations of `d` and `p` with double, rather than integer, precision.  I make use of automatic type conversion via fractional constants.  The other two options are to change the type of `sum` from an `int` to a `double`, or explicitly use a type cast (see answer by @FeihuLiu).

Minor issues:

3. Original code was formatted poorly (since fixed by one of our friends :-).
4. Optional for `main()` but it's a good idea to `return` an integer as your declaration said you would.
5. (not fixed) If you don't use `p` or `d` for anything else, consider just eliminating them in favor of doing the calculation call to `printf()`
6. It's generally a good idea to reduce the scope of variables so I moved those definitions to just before they are used.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("请输入三个整数：");
    int a, b, c;
    if (scanf("%d %d %d", &a, &b, &c) != 3) {
        // TBD: translate error message
        printf("scanf failed\n");
        return 1;
    }
    int sum = a + b + c;
    double d = sum / 3.0;
    printf("3个整数的平均值是：d=%.2f", );
    double p = 100.0 * a / sum;
    printf("，第一个数占和的比例是：p=%4.2f%%", p);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Also, division by 3

Comment: It wouldn't be a terrible idea to error check the return of `scanf` either.

Comment: And put some whitespace around `=`

Comment: The issue is not just producing a double vs an int. The operation `sum / 3` with `sum` an int is going to do integer truncation, which will be wrong

Comment: Yeah, I worded that badly.  Better now?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Thanks.  Tweaked answer.  gcc always bitches at me when I forget :-).

Answer (score 0):

Besides the `sum` problem, integer division will result in integer. You can use the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int a, b, c, sum;
    double d, p;
    printf("请输入三个整数：");
    scanf("%d %d %d", &a, &b, &c);
    sum = a + b + c;
    d = (double) sum / 3;
    printf("3个整数的平均值是：d=%.2f", d);
    p = (double) a / sum * 100;
    printf("，第一个数占和的比例是：p=%4.2f%%", p);
}
```

Comment: Please do not propagate awful formatting when answering. It's an opportunity to show what proper formatting looks like.

Comment: @Chris. That's not propagation. The question is actually formatted ok

Comment: Because I edited it. :) Check the history.

Comment: Code reformatted.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).